# The nearest object from the array of objects

Tags: data, geometry, algorithm, list-manipulation, searching

I need to find the most `similar` to desired `object` from the array of objects.

In this case `object` - something with only numeric values which we must compare(for example below it's `x` and `y` coords).

By `similarity` we mean minimal sum of differences between the corresponding values.[image]

How can I do this in the most quickest way?

P.S. Array of objects can be sorted before searching if needed.

Comment: See [`Nearest`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nearest.html).

Comment: I think it's important for us to understand what your "data structure" is. How are these different objects stored in *Mathematica*?

Comment: @corey979 thanks! And where I can find algorithm of this function?

Comment: Are you using Mathematica software? If not, your question doesn't belong on this site.

Comment: @m_goldberg yes, I already understood it. My fault

Answer (score 3):

Create some data:

```
object = RandomReal[{0, 5}, {10, 5}];

Grid @ Partition[ListPlot[#, Joined -> True, PlotRange -> 5] & /@ object, 2]
(* or in a more textbook-style: *)
Grid[Partition[Table[ListPlot[object[[i]], Joined -> True, PlotRange -> 5], {i, 1, Length[object]}], 2]]
```

[image]

and a `desired` object:

```
desired = RandomReal[{0, 5}, 5];

ListPlot[desired, Joined -> True, PlotRange -> 5]
```

[image]

According to the description: "minimal sum of differences between the corresponding values", compute

```
s = Total /@ (Abs @ Subtract[desired, #] & /@ object)
(* textbook-style: *)
s = Table[Total[Abs[desired - object[[i]]]], {i, 1, Length[object]}]
```

> {8.60733, 6.7376, 8.20597, 5.4877, 9.9549, 10.0675, 8.00134, 10.2252,
>   10.2552, 13.7893}

```
Position[s, Min @ s] (* or: Position[s, Min[s]] *)
```

> {{4}}

i.e., the fourth object is the closest to the desired one.

---

For a more general approach, see [`Nearest`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nearest.html).